# Mutlitple <!DOCTYPE html>s in a webpage

Tags: seo, html, doctype

I have a site which is divided into templates and sub-items for tempates  in the backend's template language.

However the sub-templates which are embedded into main templates each start with`<!DOCTYPE html>`. So, when I render a template as frontend there are multiple `<!DOCTYPE html>`s.

Is it bad for SEO to have multiple `<!DOCTYPE html>`s in a single page in the middle of the page and one in the top?

Should I remove them?

Comment: Is this !doctype tag inside an <iframe> tag

Comment: @Salaros No, they are all in one page. No, `<iframe>`. Then backend has a templating system where some parts are divided in smaller pieces. When rendered they are a normal page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying multiple elements `<!DOCTYPE html>` will throw an error in the **[HTML5 validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/)**. Any error on the web page has a direct or indirect effect on the search engine optimization of these webpages. In your case.

> Parsing is a very significant process within the rendering engine.
>   Parsing a document means translating it to a structure the code can
>   use. The result of parsing is usually a tree of nodes that represent
>   the structure of the document. This is called a parse tree or a syntax
>   tree. Parsing is based on the syntax rules the document obeys: the
>   language or format it was written in. Every format you can parse must
>   have deterministic grammar consisting of vocabulary and syntax rules.
>
> Parsing can be separated into two sub processes: lexical analysis and
>   syntax analysis.
>
> Lexical analysis is the process of breaking the input into tokens.
>   Tokens are the language vocabulary: the collection of valid building
>   blocks. In human language it will consist of all the words that appear
>   in the dictionary for that language.
>
> Syntax analysis is the applying of the language syntax rules.
>
> Parsers usually divide the work between two components: the lexer
>   (sometimes called tokenizer) that is responsible for breaking the
>   input into valid tokens, and the parser that is responsible for
>   constructing the parse tree by analyzing the document structure
>   according to the language syntax rules.
>
> The parsing process is iterative. The parser will usually ask the
>   lexer for a new token and try to match the token with one of the
>   syntax rules. If a rule is matched, a node corresponding to the token
>   will be added to the parse tree and the parser will ask for another
>   token.
>
> If no rule matches, the parser will store the token internally, and
>   keep asking for tokens until a rule matching all the internally stored
>   tokens is found. If no rule is found then the parser will raise an
>   exception. This means the document was not valid and contained syntax
>   errors.

Source: **[How Browsers Work: Behind the scenes of modern web browsers of HTML5 Rock](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#The_HTML_grammar_definition)**.

You can see how much work the browser does when opening a webpage. This parsing takes some time for the browser. Now imagine that in the source code of open web pages have errors. Accordingly, the **browser parsing time is increased**. Accordingly, the **speed of downloading the webpage decreases**, but this is a signal of Google's search ranking - both for **[desktops](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/04/using-site-speed-in-web-search-ranking.html)** and for **[mobile](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2018/01/using-page-speed-in-mobile-search.html)**. Thus, breaking the **[standard of HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/)** (source code errors - this is a violation of the accepted standard) you are contributing a decrease in the search rank of your webpages, that is, a negative SEO.

A possible solution to this problem is the use of a **[tag code](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_code.asp)**.

Comment: I'm not embedding code anywhere. The sub-templates are blocks that are embedded in the main template and rendered, This is some framework related stuff. So it's a complete page. So, basically you have parts of the HTML where there are `doctype`s in the middle.

Comment: Thanks! I removed the `doctype`s as there was no need for them to be there. I was just curious.

Comment: @Kotlinboy "So it's a complete page" - so presumably you have additional `head`, `title`, `meta`, `body` tags etc. as well as the `DOCTYPE` you mentioned?

Comment: @DocRoot No, only ``DOCTYPE`. The templates are blocks of HTML. `DOCTYPE` may have been added by the author to denote that this is where a block starts. These blocks combine to make a complete page

Comment: @DocRoot For example you might have multiple comments in a page. You don't know how many times theses comments are displayed. So, you create a `comment-item.html` block and in your template language(which is mixed HTML) loop through the comment items in DB and render the `comment-item.html` with the DB data. So, how many ever comments there are there will be `DOCTYPE`s in the beginning of those comments.

Answer (score 2):

It's not going to make any difference to SEO, however, my main concern would be browser rendering, since it's technically invalid markup.

However, I suspect most browsers will simply ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

The specification says that it needs to be the first thing in your document, before the `<html>` or `<head>` elements.

https://html.com/tags/doctype/

If you have them further down the page they will probably be ignored, but it depends on the browser implementation.